# Installing driver for the Nvidia GeForce GTX 760M

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried installing the Nvidia drivers for my GeForce GTX 760M in various ways:

- using the official repository:

  - package `nvidia-current`
  - package `nvidia-331`
- downloading an installation file from the Nvidia web site

---

Even though the installation seemed to be successful, I got `pre-installation script failed` message from `.run` file (the directly downloaded installation file).

After installation, I ran `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and rebooted.

---

In both cases, the system doesn't seem to use the installed driver. Going to `nvidia-settings` gives an error:

> You do not appear to be using NVIDIA X driver. Please edit you X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as `root`), and restart the X server.

---

Running `nvidia-smi` gives an error:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

`lsmod` command lists nvidia among other modules:

> nvidia              10688804  0

So, I'm totally confused. How can I change that OS is using Nvidia driver? How to get rid of the error above?

---

### UPDATE

My `nvidia-settings` opens now, but it has not many settings inside:

[image: empty nvidia-settings]

In the command line I see the following error:

> ** (nvidia-settings:4334): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
>
> ** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

The command `inxi -Gx` (whatever it does) gives me:

> Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
>   Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
>              X.Org: 1.14.3 **drivers: nouveau,intel (unloaded: nvidia,fbdev,vesa)** Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
>              GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A Direct Rendering: N/A

So I can conclude that the Nvidia driver is not used. How to fix it?

Comment: Try `nvidia-driver-418` according to [Nvidia Driver page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for installing OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (as of April 2019) on a recent PC (Asus G20) with both Intel & nVidia (GTX970) graphics controllers:

- in the BIOS settings, BOOT parameters, you can continue to use UEFI mode, but change the OS from "Windows" to "Other OS"
- if your installation of OpenSUSE crashes, hangs, or fails with an unexpected error, try adding these options to the kernel boot line (press 'e' in the Grub boot screen): textmode=1 nomodeset acpi=off splash=verbose
- you may need to do this each time when you run the 'Installation' or 'Update' option
- after installing on an Asus G20, the following kernel options are recommended permanently, which you can set in Yast, Boot, Kernel parameters: pci=acpi pci=noaer splash=silent
- also, it is suggested to install a minimum system in the non-graphics mode first, just to get the system running, then download the nVidia drivers for X using Yast from the Nvidia OpenSUSE repo, which is described here: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers
- install the appropriate for your graphics card. I used for a GTX970:
- the 'x11-video-nvidiaG05' driver, then 'nvidia-glG05' for OpenGL 3D acceleration
- then run 'Update' to bring the system up to graphics mode

This problem was submitted to OpenSUSE.

Possible causes:

- PCI Advaced Error Reporting (AER) floods the system log
- possible conflicts between the Intel and nVidia controllers prior to nVidia drivers being installed cause crash